# Changing each entry in a list returned from powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a list of paths (filtered by special criteria). I want to mutate each entry in this list, but can't find a way (I think it's immutable). What's the best way of going about this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I guess you have some collection, not only list (probably array).

```
PS> $myList = 'first','second','third'
```

You can mutate the collection by indexing or just by creating new array like this:

```
PS> $myList[1] = '2nd'
#or
PS> $myList | % { $_.Substring(0,2) }
  fi
  se
  th
```